# From locally I can access through teminal using psql command but not able to connect through JAVA code

Tags: java, linux, postgresql-11

I have tried to connect remote postgresql through JAVA code but i am getting this error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the
>   hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting
>   TCP/IP connections.   at

But I am able to access remote postgres DB through terminal outside.
Please help me in below code.

I have made all required changes in postgres conf and pg_hba files.

```
1) postgresql.conf
==> change to localhost='*'
2) pg_hba.conf
==> add below lines at end of the line
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5
```

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JDBCExample {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        System.out.println("-------- PostgreSQL "
                + "JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

        try {

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? "
                    + "Include in your library path!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://X.X.X.X:5432/mydb", "myuser",
                    "mypassword");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "I have made all required changes in postgres conf and pg_hba files." please add them to the question

Comment: question updated and added changes in conf files.

Comment: I am able to connect postgresql DB through terminal remotely.
$ psql -h X.X.X.X -p 5432 -d mydb -U myuser -W